# Angularjs mock a function that returns an $http promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

I have and angularjs app in which I have a controller that calls a service that returns an $http call.  The app works fine, but I am trying to test the controller and running into issues.

My service:

```
myApp.factory("MyService", function ($http) {
     var service = {};

     service.save = function (item) {
         return $http.post('../api/Save', item)
             .success(function () {
                 console.log("Saved items on current page");
             })
             .error(function () {
                 console.log("Error saving items on page")
             });
         };
      return service;
});
```

My controller:

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.save = function () {
       MyService.save($scope.data)
        .success(function () {
            //do something
        }).error(function () {
            //do something else
        });
    };        
});
```

The app works exactly as expected.

My spec file:

```
describe('MyCtrl', function () {
    var myCtrl, mySvc, scope;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('MyApp');
        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.service('MyService', function () {
                this.save = function () { };
            });
        });
        inject(function ($injector) {
            mySvc = $injector.get('MyService');
        });
        spyOn(mySvc, 'save').and.callFake(function () {
            return {
                success: function (callback) {
                    callback({ /* something */ });
                },
                error: function (callback) { 
                    callback({/* something else */ }); 
                }
            };
        });
        inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            myCtrl = $controller('MyCtrl', { $scope: scope });
        });
    });
    describe('when save button has been hit', function () {
        it('should save', function () {
            scope.save();
            expect(mySvc.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

The test gives me an error that `'undefined' is not an object (near '...}).error(function () {...')`.  If I remove the `'...}).error(function () {...')` portion from the controller itself then the test works fine, but I don't want to get rid of that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try using return callback()

```
   spyOn(mySvc, 'save').and.callFake(function () {
        return {
            success: function (callback) {
                return callback({ /* something */ });
            },
            error: function (callback) { 
                return callback({/* something else */ }); 
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: I don't use success/error style promises. I always use then/catch syntax. Have you tried mocking that instead? `return {
                    then: function(callback) { 
                        return callback(true); 
                    }
                };` I don't see how that is different but I don't see anything else wrong with your test.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  I still get the same error if I am chaining the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I got something working! The issue is that in my controller I am chaining the response behavior, which the mocked function doesn't know how to handle. The solution I found was to direct back to the function after each case.

```
 $provide.service('MyService', function () {
       this.save = function () {
            return {
                 success: function (callback) {
                    callback();
                    return this;
                 }, 
                 error: function (callback) {
                    callback();
                    return this;
                 },
                 finally: function (callback) {
                    callback();
                    return this;
                 }
            };
       };
  });
```

and then change the spy to just:

```
spyOn(mySvc, 'save').and.callThrough();
```